# Import Series using fredapi on Python

Tags: python, series

I am trying to import the "6-Month London Interbank Offered Rate (LIBOR), based on Euro" series from the St Louis Fed database using Python.

I am using the fredapi package on Python using the following codes:

```
import fedapi
from fredapi import Fred

fred = Fred(api_key = 'my_api_key')
data = fred.get_series('EUR6MTD156N')
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Not Found.  The series does not exist.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `EUR6MTD156N` might be a key which `fedapi` doesn't support.

Comment: Yes, you're right, maybe the series available through the ```fedapi``` module are limited. Thanks for your comment.